# Finding ‎the level ‎curves ‎of $z= f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $$‎z=‎\cos x‎‎‎\cos y‎‎‎\exp\left(\sqrt{‎‎‎\dfrac{x‎‎‎^{‎2‎}‎+y^{2‎}‎}{‎4‎}‎‎‎‎‎}‎\right)$$ please hint me to find the level ‎curves ‎of ‎‎it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AliQurbani Level sets are curves when $z$ is fixed, for example
$$
\cos x \cos y \exp \left ( \sqrt {\frac {x^2+y^2}4}\right ) = 10
$$
or 5, or any other value. So that curve would be 10, 5 or whatever value you chose level set. General form of it is
$$
\cos x \cos y \exp \left ( \sqrt {\frac {x^2+y^2}4}\right ) = F
$$
meaning it's not $z$ anymore, i.e. variable or function, etc.
Some level sets are plotted below

[image: levelsets]

Answer (score 0):

Asking [WolframAlpha](http://bit.ly/Yz4Pxz) I get a nice plot:

[image: 3D Contour Plot]

Comment: This is not level sets.

Comment: I want the equation of it.

Comment: See : http://www.mediafire.com/view/?j9ek1me47a43c#